# Regex check text if contains a phrase

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression that basically does the following: let's say I have this phrase: "My neighbour driving a yellow car is cool" .  I basically want a regular expression that matches this sentence. However, "driving a yellow car" is optional, but if it appears, I would like to grab the word yellow.

Comment: I don't know about regex flavors, but if It helps you, I'm writing it in Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
My\sneighbour\s(?:driving\sa\s(?<color>yellow)\scar)?\sis\scool
```

Answer (score 0):

With PHP it would be:

```
if ( preg_match( '/My\sneighbour\s(driving\sa\s.+\scar)?\sis\scool/', $originalString ); ) {
    $color = preg_replace ( '/My\sneighbour\s(driving\sa\s(.+)\scar)?\sis\scool/', '$2', $originalString );
}
```